# Проблема с закреплением меню в тильде зеро блок на javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation, menu, tilda

Салют, всем! У меня есть небольшая проблемка. Я закрепил менюшку в блоке тильды через код:

#rec1234567 { width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 9997; }

Но так как блок полностью накладывается на остальные блоки, то не получается пользователю нажать на ссылки, которые находятся под блоком меню. Как это можно исправить? Через z-index не помогло. Прошу прощения за некомпетентность и заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Никак :) Если только ссылки не будут выше блока, что уже некрасиво. Можно в принципе скрывать меню при скролле вниз (и показывать при скролле на вверх), тогда и на ссылки можно будет нажать.

Comment: @ΝNL993 у меня кнопка с ссылкой находится в самом конце. 

Как вы сказали, ее можно сделать выше этого блока. Она у меня посередине, поэтому даже выдвигающееся меню перекрывать не будет. Но только как это сделать? z-inxex не помог

Или как сделать так, чтобы при скролле к этому последнему блоку, где находится кнопка, в конце страницы, этот блок с меню скрывался?

Comment: Да её можно сделать выше `position: relative; z-index: 9998;`. Скрыть меню при появлении кнопки можно так: если `btn.offsetTop < window.pageYOffset + window.screen.height` тогда `menu.style.top = '125vh'`. (Нужно делать эту проверку при событии `scroll`)

Comment: @ΝNL993 вы гений! спасибо большое! про пункт position: relative не знал)))

Comment: Спасибо :) Да, используя `position: relative`, любому элементу можно задавать `z-index` (и он не будет менять своего положения).